# How to use nhibernate search? Can't get it to successfully build

Tags: .net, nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate-search

I am trying to hookup nhibernate search but ran into a couple problems.

1. I downloaded the [nuget package](https://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Search/) and I am getting errors

   The type 'Lucene.Net.Search.Query' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

It seems like it does not have the right version. Is there a more up to date version that I can get? I can't seem to find one.

2 the next error I get is

```
 string query = "Name: Test";
                using (var nhibernateSearch = Search.CreateFullTextSession(unitOfWork.Session))
                {
                    base.unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();


                    var carSearchResults = nhibernateSearch.CreateFullTextQuery(query)
                        .SetMaxResults(5)
                        .List();

                    //var results = nhibernateSearch.CreateFullTextQuery(query).List();


                    base.unitOfWork.Commit();
                }
```

I get

```
The best overloaded method match for 'NHibernate.Search.IFullTextSession.CreateFullTextQuery(Lucene.Net.Search.Query, params System.Type[])' has some invalid arguments
```

3 Next error I get is

```
Error   13  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Lucene.Net.Search.Query'
```

I been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/03/04/Nhibernate-Search-Tutorial-with-LuceneNet-and-NHibernate-30.aspx) and so far it seems like alot has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your first problem.

You're calling `CreateFulltextQuery(Query, params Type[])`, but it sounds like you want to call `CreateFulltextQuery<MyEntityType>(String)` instead.

Based on your variable name I'm guessing ...

```
var carSearchResults = nhibernateSearch.CreateFullTextQuery<Car>(query)
                                       .SetMaxResults(5)
                                       .List();
```